# Socket read failing in gdb, OK when run outside gdb

Tags: c, sockets, gdb

I have a problem where running some socket code in gdb is causing the socket read to fail, whereas it seems to work when run normally outside of gdb

I need to be able to debug this, so I have to figure out what is going on.

the code looks like this:

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0) 
    error("ERROR opening socket");
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
    error("ERROR on binding");
}
listen(sockfd,5);
printf("Daemon listening on host %s port %d...\n\n",
       hostname, portno);
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

/* accept() blocks until a socket connection is found */
newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

if (newsockfd < 0) 
    error("ERROR on accept");
else
    printf("Daemon found socket connection "
           "(newsockfd = %d) ready to read...\n\n", newsockfd);

bzero(buf,65536);
buf_no = 1;
while(1) {
    n = read(newsockfd, buf, MAX_TRACK_TABLE_SIZE);
    printf("read() returns %d, errno = %d\n", n, errno);
    perror("Error");
...
```

I run this in conjunction with a python script that just sends messages over the socket, for this c-code to receive and process

When I run the C application from the cmd line I get expected results, i.e. n is set to no. of bytes recvd and the string coming over the socket is placed in buf.

However, when I run the application in gdb, the call to read() returns -1, with an errno of 14 corresptonding to a 'Bad address' error

I can't think what could be causing the difference in behaviour between running inside and outside of gdb?

Comment: gdb is probably timing out the socket read operation as it is under the control of the debugger.

Comment: any possibility of a workaround?

Comment: Simple, there is no workaround! gdb is waiting for the next instruction under control. Use wireshark to monitor the duplex packets in both directions.

Comment: so maybe gdb is not so useful for debugging socket apps?

Comment: You can try to set infinite timeouts on socket when running this code in gdb.

Comment: On Unix/Linux, gdb disables ASLR by default. Try `set disable-randomization off` to get closer to the way a program is run outside gdb. Read may be getting EFAULT because `buf` is an invalid address. Without seeing more code, it's hard to guess why - maybe a failed malloc or a buffer overrun of an array declared adjacent to `buf` -  but try printing the value of `buf` in gdb and see if it's a sensible address.

Comment: It should work. I guess there's an overflow somewhere where you crashed parts of your stack. What is e.g. buf?